# Evaluate $\oint_C F.dr$ where $F = (x-z)i +(2y)j +(x+z)k$

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, stokes-theorem

I'm having trouble figuring out
$$
\oint_C \underline{F} \cdot d\underline{r},
$$
where $\underline{F} = (x-z)\underline i +2y\underline j +(x+z)\underline k$ and in which $C$ is a closed path in the $xz$ plane.

First thing I thought to do was to use Stoke's Theorem:

$$\oint_C \underline F \cdot d\underline r = \iint_S\ \nabla \times \underline F \cdot d\underline S =\iint_S\ \nabla × (x-z, 2y, x+z) \cdot d\underline S$$

I found the cross product to equal to $(0,-2,0)$.

I'm not sure what to do from this point (assuming what I did is correct).
Would really appreciate some guidance.

Edit:

The graph of C in the xz plane is below.

[image: path of integral]

What would the limits of x and z be in this case( when im calculating the integral)?

Comment: What you've done so far is right. The only thing left is to find out which way $\underline S$ is pointing and then you're basically done.

Comment: Great! How do i do that? @Skip

Comment: Use the fact that $C$ is in the $xy$ plane.

Comment: My bad, that was suppose to say xz plane not xy. I have changed it now. So if its in the xz plane then it would point outward in the y plane?? @Skip

Comment: Right, in the $y$ direction.

Comment: so in that case am i suppose to find the normal $n$ and then $S = n.dxdz/(n.j)$ @Skip

Comment: $d \underline S = \hat{n} \, dx \, dz$ but $\hat{n}$ is already known. I don't want to tell it to you directly but I will say you're staring right at it when you read $C$ is in the $xz$ plane.

Comment: Right, so $dS = jdxdz $ ?? @Skip

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: cool. Btw i added the graph of C to my edits. What limits would i use when i calculate the integral. Would it just be 1<x<8 and 1<z<10? Thanks for your help, i really appreciate it. @Skip

Comment: No problem. If the limits are constant then that describes a rectangle, which isn't what we have. That would be a pretty annoyingly complicated curve to trace out but we're lucky in that $\nabla \times F \cdot j$ is a constant. So what can we say then?

Comment: @Skip im honestly not sure. Can i have another hint?

Comment: Since it's constant, we can pull it out of the integral and then we're left with finding $\iint_S dx \, dz.$ What does this represent?

Comment: Ahh i see! It represents the area? @Skip

Comment: Yeah. And since $C$ was assumed to be oriented counterclockwise but it's not, I believe the final result should be multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: Got it, thank again! @Skip

Comment: You're welcome!